# Go not finding unmarshaled XML node

Tags: go

I'm trying to unmarshal an XML file, but it's not finding my root node `snapshot`, which is keeping me from being able to unmarshal the rest of my file.

I'm calling `parser.go` from `main.go`, as well as the `Validate` function.

> parser.go

```
type Parser struct {
    file     *ConfigXML
    filepath string
}

//Load the file
func (parser *Parser) Load() error {
    b, err := helpers.LoadFile(parser.filepath)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    parser.file = nil
    xml.Unmarshal(b, &parser.file)

    return nil
}

func (parser *Parser) Validate() error {

    if len(parser.file.snapshot) == 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("node snapshot does not exist")
    }

    return nil
}
```

While my XML file is large, I'll post a snippet:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <snapshot>
  <ENBEquipment id="233443234543" model="XYZ" version="LR_16_02_L">
   <attributes>
    <administrativeState>unlocked</administrativeState>
   </attributes>
  </ENBEquipment>
 </snapshot>
```

The structs I've created to unmarshal to:

```
type ConfigXML struct {
    snapshot []Snapshot
    FileName string
}

// Snapshot is root <snapshot>
type Snapshot struct {
    ENBEquipment []ENBEquipment
}

// ENBEquipment subtag of <snapshot> -> <ENBEquipment>
type ENBEquipment struct {
    ID              string `xml:"id,attr"`
    DeviceName      string `xml:"id,attr"`
    SoftwareVersion string `xml:"version,attr"`
    ElementType     string `xml:"model,attr"`
    Enb             []Enb
}
```

However when I attempt to run with `go run main.go`, I get:

```
ERRO[2018-06-12 09:45:34] parsing failed    error="node snapshot does not exist" filename=/tmp/datain/xyz/123/agg/233443234543.xml
```

If I take out the Validation of `snapshot`, the file unmarshals fine. Why is this not finding the node?

Comment: What do you see when using debug breakpoints or `fmt.Println()` for `parser.file` ?

Comment: Full disclosure, I'm still learning Go.  Where did have in mind for me to place the `Println()` @Derek

Comment: Also, you should really be capturing and handling the potential error returned by `xml.Unmarshal()`

Comment: Also, please add the definition of `ConfigXML` type

Comment: The `ConfigXML` type is there (the formatting had a typo). @Godzilla74, are you still running into trouble with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try exporting `snapshot` and adding a struct tag indicate the name.

`xml.Unmarshal` uses reflection to populate the the struct. So, the elements of the struct need to be exported.

```
type ConfigXML struct {
    Snapshot []Snapshot `xml:"snapshot"`
    FileName string
}
```

See [the GoDoc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) (search for "exported" and check out the example) for additional information about how `xml.Unmarshal` works.